# How to get mysql data from the server in my local?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the data from the mysql-server which is hosted with **AWS** to my local machine.

Its working without any error but I cannot see my data.

**dbconf.php**

```
function get_data(){

    $dbhost = 'serverip';
    $dbport = '3306';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'passs';
    $rowarray = array();
    $conn = mysql_connect("$dbhost","$dbport","$dbuser","$dbpass");
    mysql_select_db("register");
    $sql = "select * from users'";
    $res =mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))  {
        $rowarray[] = $row;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print (json_encode($rowarray,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

**index.php**

```
if (isset($_GET["action"])  == "get_data") {
    $user_list = file_get_contents('http://myserverip/testfile/dbconf.php?action=get_data');
    $user_list = json_decode($user_list, true);
```

**output**

> [
>   ]  //returning as json

Comment: you will have to post full code

Comment: Was user root have full permissions on that database?

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM How do i check that permission?

Comment: If you have some GUI you will need have some USERS in your database, or you can see from SSH or some, witch OS you have?

Comment: @ONLINETELEKOM Am using Ubuntu 14.04 ... May i use phpmyadmin?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OE5WanVr9-8 - tuttorial for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi use pdo dont use mysql is old function:

```
    function Conn($user = 'GreenForex', $pass = 'password', $host = 'localhost', $database = 'GreenForex', $port = 3306){
    $c = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';port='.$port.';dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
    // don't cache query
    $c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    // show warning text
    $c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    // throw error exception
    $c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // don't colose connecion on script end
    $c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);
    // set utf for connection utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci 
    // $c->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");
    $c->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
    return $c;
    }

$db = Conn();
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$o = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // If you dont know how looks array structure print_r($o); !!!!!
echo json_encode($o);
```

Or for jquery .each():

```
$db = Conn();
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users where id != 0");
$o = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // If you dont know how looks array structure print_r($o); !!!!!
$out = array();
$out['users'] = $o;
echo json_encode($out);
```

How secure input data (mysql query):

```
// Secure data (sql injection) $q = "SELECT FROM user WHERE nick='$nick' id = 1";
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
$nick = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/", "", $_POST['nick']);
$email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
$pass1 = md5($_POST['pass1']);
```

Or you can use bindParam:

```
<?php
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```